# Virtual network tab on windows azure isn't available

Tags: networking, azure, virtual

i made a virtual network on windows azure to make site to site VPN .after creating this virtual network and adding  gateway with dynamic routing i found network tab has red exclamation mark and disabled.so i can't log in this tab and can't create new network.it displays a message to reload or refresh my web browser.

Answer (score 0):

The red exclamation point appears from time to time if there is an error loading data for that feature.  This can happen when the portal code running in your browser requests data on the back end and that fails for some reason.  Many times this is just a transient issue.  When this happens I usually refresh the browser to see if it was a transient problem, and if that doesn't fix the issue I go check the status board for the particular service (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/).

If it continues to be an issue and there is nothing on the status board indicating a problem you can contact support, if you have a support plan.